# select from index to index

Tags: php, sql

I am building pagination and am not familiar with SQL. I need help to parse an SQL statement.

For example, I have following array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

By selecting **from index 2 to index 4**, I get

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

To do the similar thing in SQL, for example, this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE birthday BETWEEN '2001-01-01' AND '2020-01-01'
```

gives the result

```
{
    "Jason": ...
    "Mary": ...
    "Josh": ...
    "Peter": ...
    "Laren": ...
    "Dan": ...
}
```

I only want the 3~5th items from the array. which

```
{
    "Peter": ...
    "Laren": ...
    "Dan": ...
}
```

To be specific, is there a way I can pass in a starting index and an ending index into the SQL statement to only collect segments of records of certain length?

I don't want to manipulate data in PHP since I worry about RAM and performance. I am a newbie so any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Doesn't the `LIMIT start, length` clause do what you want?

Comment: Don't forget to use `ORDER BY`, otherwise the use of limit is unpredictable.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

Use 'offset' and 'limit':

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE birthday BETWEEN '2001-01-01' AND '2020-01-01' LIMIT 3, 5
```